# Android RatingBar with corrupt layout in an Actionbar.Tab fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

I have a question regarding the standard rating bar control in Android. I'm using Android Studio 0.5.8 and a HTC One for debugging. The ratingbar is displayed in a listView control.
In my custom adapter I set the following value:

```
    myRatingbar = (RatingBar) row.findViewById(R.id.myRatingbar);
    myRatingbar.setRating(product.getRating());
```

I'm adding the RatingBar control with the following code:

```
     <RatingBar
        style = "?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars = "5"
        android:stepSize="0.1"
        android:id="@+id/myRatingbar"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="4"/>
```

When adding the listview to a normal activity everything is fine. When I add the listview to a fragment in a Actionbar.tab then it destroys the layout of the ratingbar. When I set the rating 3.0 inside of an activity it displays three stars. If I set the rating inside the fragment it displays my five stars in a row and overlapping stars at the bottom of the rating bar.

Activity -> ListView and the RatingBar is ok
[ratingbar ok](http://i60.tinypic.com/2gy4n7d.png)

Activity-> Actionbar.Tab -> Fragment -> Listview and the ratingbar looks like:
[Ratingbar not OK](http://i60.tinypic.com/20ivy3c.png)

I'm using the same code and the same layout.xml but only inside a ActionBar.Tab -> fragment instead of an activity.
I tried a lot to fix the issue and really can't find the root cause. I followed some tutorials and searched here on stackoverflow to get an answer. I also tried to add custom actionbar images with the same result.

As this is my first post and I'm not precise enough please tell me which information you should need to help me troubleshooting the issue.

*EDIT* : If the stars are empty(without rating) everything is rendered correct see this image -> http://i60.tinypic.com/jku5ir.png

Comment: Hi again, anyone an idea?